# Comparing two large csv files and searching for similar rows

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have 'conm' csv file that contains about 16,000 rows of company names and 'contract' csv file that contains about half a million rows with company names and corresponding [duns_number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Universal_Numbering_System).

conm.csv

```
AAR CORP
ACF INDUSTRIES HOLDING CORP
ADC TELECOMMUNICATIONS INC
AFA PROTECTIVE SYSTEMS INC
AFP IMAGING CORP
ALPHARMA INC  -CL A
........
```

contract.csv

```
"PRIME DENTAL SUPPLY INC.","088371229"
"MCMANIS ASSOCIATES INC","072637457"
"AT&T GOVERNMENT SOLUTIONS, INC","009683442"
"INPRO CORPORATION","106722606"
"MEDTRONIC, INC.","006261481"
"G C MICRO CORPORATION","157637570"
.......
```

As you can see, the contract.csv is not ordered.

I am trying to see whether the company name in conm.csv is in contract.csv. **However**, the problem is that the company name in conm.csv and contract.csv are, many of the time, not exactly same... Many have spelling mistakes, some contain extra unnecessary words, or the order of the words are exchanged in some cases.

So I have decided compare row by row to find matches by performing below method:

1. clean up the strings by removing special characters
2. see whether they are perfect match
3. if not use fuzzy-wuzzy library to measure the ratio of two string, and pass if the ratio is > 95

Here is my code so far.

```
write_csv = open('result.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(write_csv)

with open(filename1, 'r') as f1:
    with open(filename2, 'r') as f2:        
        conm = csv.reader(f1)
        contract = csv.reader(f2)

        # save the conm file into list
        contract = list(contract)

        try:
            for row1 in conm:
                # row to be appended in result.csv
                row = []
                name1 = simplify_string(row1[0])

                for row2 in contract:
                    name2 = simplify_string(row2[0])
                    if check_same(name1, name2):
                        row.extend([name1, row2[1]])
                    elif fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name1, name3) > 95:
                            row.extend([name1, row2[1]])

                if len(row) > 1:
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

The simplify_string method removes all punctuations and etc to clean up strings in conm.csv and contract.csv.

The problem of this code is that I do not know whether this code catches all matches and does not add any noises. So it is inevitable to edit and run this code several times...

However, this code runs extremely slow. Last time it took more than 4 days in my i5 cpu computer.

I was wondering if there is a method to improve performance. Or perhaps there is a clever way in solving this kind of problem??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is your simplify_string() method using regular expressions? If not, it should, so it would clean the parameters faster. An example:

```
import re
def simplify_string(myString):
    return re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', cad)
```

This regular expression [^\w] in re.sub() method replaces non alphanumeric characters with spaces. You could also replace them by another character or an empty string. For example:

```
>>> someString = "This $String is go%ing to become clean, you'll see."
>>> simplify_string(someString):
'This String is go ing to become clean you ll see'
```

Maybe this regexp is not enough accurate for your needs, but you can build more powerful ones. Here's a link that explains deeper how to build and use regular expressions:

[Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

This may make it a little faster. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, my simplify_string method does use regex. The major part that slows down this program is the nested looping...